# Android-Firebase ChangeValueEventListener stopped working for Android API 27 (version 8.1 or less)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.android

I am using firebase Realtime database for past 6+ months in my Xamarin. Android Application. It worked well. But now I faced problem With Android Version 8.1 or Less that Listener stopped working. I didn't changed anything in code but it is neither reading nor writing. It Is Still Working For Android Version 9.0 or Greater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Resolved this issue by reset my internet router. Due to some reason my router block the request which causes the problem.